# Entity Framework - Modifying The edmx Automatically

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to change the names of some navigation properties in the model auto-generated from the database. How can I add a logic to modify the edmx automatically right after I use the wizard to generate the model from the database.

Comment: Generate the model using the EF Reverse POCO template instead

Comment: @ErikEJ I am making the changes on the database, so code-first approach will not do it for me.

Comment: That template is for exactly using database first - did you even look at it?